# merge two rows in excel, and move a column next to the last column

Tags: excel

How in excel could i merge all rows that share the same value in column A, by adding the contents of each of the rest columns, into new columns appended to the last existing column of the first row?

```
A B C
A 2 3
A 4 6

Result:
A B C 2 3 4 6
```

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: the CONCATENATE function, with no success

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Change All to Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Change All to Text", {"Column1"}, "Temp1", "Value"),
    #"Removed Temp1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Temp1"}),
    #"Grouped Column1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Temp1", {"Column1"}, {{"Temp2", each _, type table}}),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Column1", "Value", each Text.Combine([Temp2][Value],",")),
    #"Removed Temp2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Values",{"Temp2"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Temp2", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv))
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: never used Power Query before, i will give it a try, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think a little VBA might also do the trick.  Something like this:

```
Sub MergeAppend()

  Dim row As Range
  Dim lastVal As String
  Dim lastRow, lastCol, i As Integer

  For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    If lastVal = row.Cells(1, 1).Value2 Then
      For i = 2 To row.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        If Cells(row.row, i).Value2 <> "" Then
          Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Value2 = Cells(row.row, i).Value2
          lastCol = lastCol + 1
        End If
      Next i
    Else
      lastVal = row.Cells(1, 1).Value2
      lastRow = row.row
      lastCol = row.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1
    End If


  Next row

End Sub
```